# If/else and while branches in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, reflection.emit, mono.cecil

AFAIK, Cecil does not support `DefineLabel` and `MarkLabel`. What are the alternatives to use (e.g. generating `Nop` opcodes) to replace labels when working with if-else and while branches?

For example:

```
public void Run(bool someParam)
{
    int someInt = 0;
    while (someParam)
    {
        someInt = someInt + 1;
        if (someInt == 10) someParam = false;
        System.Console.WriteLine(someInt);
    }
}
```

would have the following decompiled Reflection.Emit codes:

```
Label whileLabel = gen.DefineLabel();
Label label1 = gen.DefineLabel();
Label label2 = gen.DefineLabel();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S,label1);
gen.MarkLabel(whileLabel);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S,10);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S,label2);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Starg_S,1);
gen.MarkLabel(label2);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call,writeLineMethod);
gen.MarkLabel(label1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S,whileLabel);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

What could I do to "mark" labels in Cecil?

Comment: IIRC an branch `Instruction` in mono.cecil saves the target of the branch directly as the operand in form of the corresponding `Instruction` object..

Answer (score 2):

Basically you pass the target instruction when creating the jump, something like:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using Mono.Cecil.Rocks;
using System; 
using System.Linq;
using BindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

using Cecilifier.Runtime;

public class SnippetRunner
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(new AssemblyNameDefinition("name", Version.Parse("1.0.0.0")), "moduleName", ModuleKind.Dll);
        var t1 = new TypeDefinition("", "Foo", TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.NotPublic, assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Object);
        assembly.MainModule.Types.Add(t1);
        t1.BaseType = assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Object;
        var Foo_ctor_ = new MethodDefinition(".ctor", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Void);
        t1.Methods.Add(Foo_ctor_);
        var il1 = Foo_ctor_.Body.GetILProcessor();
        var Ldarg_02 = il1.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il1.Append(Ldarg_02);
        var Call3 = il1.Create(OpCodes.Call, assembly.MainModule.ImportReference(TypeHelpers.DefaultCtorFor(t1.BaseType)));
        il1.Append(Call3);
        var Ret4 = il1.Create(OpCodes.Ret);
        il1.Append(Ret4);

        var Foo_F_int32 = new MethodDefinition("F", MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Void);
        t1.Methods.Add(Foo_F_int32);
        var il_Foo_F_int32 = Foo_F_int32.Body.GetILProcessor();
        var x5 = new ParameterDefinition("x", ParameterAttributes.None, assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Int32);
        Foo_F_int32.Parameters.Add(x5);
        // if (x < 10)
        var Ldarg_16 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Ldarg_16);
        var Ldc_I47 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 10);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Ldc_I47);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Clt));
        var esp8 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Nop);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Brfalse, esp8));
        //if body

// x = x + 1;
        var Ldarg_19 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Ldarg_19);
        var Ldc_I410 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Ldc_I410);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Add));
        var Starg_S11 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Starg_S, x5);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Starg_S11);
        var ese12 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Nop);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(esp8);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(ese12);
        Foo_F_int32.Body.OptimizeMacros();
        var Ret13 = il_Foo_F_int32.Create(OpCodes.Ret);
        il_Foo_F_int32.Append(Ret13);

        assembly.Write(args[0]);
    }
}
```

By the way, the code above has been generated by this tool (https://cecilifier.me) (that can help you to learn about Mono.Cecil) with the following code:

```
class Foo
{
   void F(int x)
   {
     if (x < 10)
     {
         x = x + 1;
     }
   }
}
```